# String operation in Python

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of strings

```
['ABC 12whwe', 'DCFB 23cbd','WWERD 121wed','AD 234F','B 12e2e']
```

what I want is a list containing strings upto and not including the space from the above list. To clarify, below is the answer for the above list

```
['ABC', 'DCFB','WWERD','AD','B']
```

how do I do that?

thanks,

Comment: Search after `split()`, there are plenty of resources out there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just split each string by white spaces and take the first element, before the first space. This should work:

```
lst = ['ABC 12whwe', 'DCFB 23cbd','WWERD 121wed','AD 234F','B 12e2e']
[s.split()[0] for s in lst]
=> ['ABC', 'DCFB', 'WWERD', 'AD', 'B']
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
a=[i.split()[0] for i in ['ABC 12whwe', 'DCFB 23cbd','WWERD 121wed','AD 234F','B 12e2e']]
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.